# NSBundle and Accessing Folder inside Resources Folder

Tags: iphone

I have Images folder inside the Resources folder which contains images. I am using the following code to access the images but the resultant array always comes out to be empty:

```
NSArray *imagesPath = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"gif" inDirectory:@"Images"];
```

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images" ofType:nil]` do you get the correct path for that folder?
If not are you sure that is a folder and not a simple group?

Comment: Oh!! You are right! It is not a folder. It is a group. How do I add a folder inside the Resources folder since when I right click on Resources there is no option to add a new folder.

Comment: when you try to do add>existing files... select the folder and then check the 'Create folder references' instead of 'Recursively create groups'